Resolving Errors in AndroidManifest.xml for Flutter Android App
I'm new to flutter and I'm working on setting up my Android project to accept speech to text. After setting the minimum SDK to 21 and including necessary permissions in AndroidManifest.xml, I am still facing several unresolved issues.
1.) Unresolved class ${applicationName}
2.) Cannot resolve symbol @mipmap/ic_launcher
3.) Unresolved class .MainActivity
4.) Cannot resolve symbols @style/LaunchTheme and @style/NormalTheme
5.)Errors about using attributes like hardwareAccelerated and windowSoftInputMode with my current min SDK setting (API level 21)
I added the permissions and thought everything would be good. I saw a post about maybe downgrading but I saw other posts saying different things so I wasn't sure what the best solution was.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <application
        android:label="myapp"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>



These error are shown because you're currently in flutter environment and flutter don't recognize xml files. If you want to edit native android code: right click on android folder > flutter > click open android module in android studio. This will open the android module in new window and after gradle sync, you can edit your android files.
